# Rotate object from one coordinate system to another

Tags: opengl, 3d, glm-math

Using the `glm` library for the calculations. I have a mesh located in a local coordinate system where the axis are:

```
meshUp =      glm::vec3(0, 1, 0);
meshForward = glm::vec3(0, 0, -1);
meshRight =   glm::vec3(1, 0, 0);
```

and I need a matrix that will rotate its vertices to any other new coordinate system with 3 given axis, fx:

```
newUp =       glm::vec3(-0.85, 0.51, -0.08);
newForward =  glm::vec3(0.45, 0.65, -0.61);
newRight =    glm::vec3(-0.26, -0.56, -0.79);
```

No translation needed, the coordinate systems share origin. I can get halfway there, like this:

```
glm::vec3 rotationVecForUpAxis = glm::normalize(glm::cross(meshUp, newUp));
float rotationRadiansForUpAxis = acos(glm::dot(meshUp, newUp));

glm::mat4 rotationMatrix = glm::rotate(glm::mat4(), 
                                       rotationRadiansForUpAxis,
                                       rotationVecForUpAxis);
```

This works and rotates the mesh, so it's up axis aligns with the `newUp` axis. However, the mesh still needs to be rotated around the `newUp` axis, before the mesh's `meshForward` axis aligns with the `newForward` axis.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: It looks like you might be interested in a change of basis matrix: https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/changebasis/.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could look up the math. But just for the fun of it, I'm going to derive it here.

Let's say that the new basis vectors, expressed in the original coordinate system, are:

```
     [ xnx ]         [ ynx ]         [ znx ]
xn = [ xny ]    yn = [ yny ]    zn = [ zny ]
     [ xnz ]         [ ynz ]         [ znz ]
```

You're looking for the matrix `M` that maps these vectors to the basis vectors in the new coordinate system:

```
    [ xnx ] = [ 1 ]        [ ynx ] = [ 0 ]        [ znx ] = [ 0 ]
M * [ xny ] = [ 0 ]    M * [ yny ] = [ 1 ]    M * [ zny ] = [ 0 ]
    [ xnz ] = [ 0 ]        [ ynz ] = [ 0 ]        [ znz ] = [ 1 ]
```

Writing this in matrix form gives:

```
    [ xnx  ynx  znx ] = [ 1  0  0 ]
M * [ xny  yny  zny ] = [ 0  1  0 ]
    [ xnz  ynz  znz ] = [ 0  0  1 ]
```

Which in turn gives for `M`:

```
             [ xnx  ynx  znx ]
M = inverse( [ xny  yny  zny ] )
             [ xnz  ynz  znz ]
```

In words, the matrix is the inverse of the matrix that has the new basis vectors as its columns.

For a rotation, this becomes particularly easy. The inverse of a rotation matrix is the transpose of the matrix. So `M` is the matrix with the new basis vectors as its rows:

```
    [ xnx  xny  xnz ]
M = [ ynx  yny  ynz ]
    [ znx  zny  znz ]
```

With this, all you need to get your rotation matrix is build a matrix that has the values of the new basis vectors as its rows. For example, if you use `newRight` as the x-axis, `newUp` as the y-axis, and `newForward` as the z-axis, the transformation matrix is:

```
[ newRight.x    newRight.y    newRight.z   ]
[ newUp.x       newUp.y       newUp.z      ]
[ newForward.x  newForward.y  newForward.z ]
```

When building the matrix, keep in mind that matrices for OpenGL are commonly stored in column major order.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering, it works beautifully, and is so much simpler than the direction I was heading!

Comment: great answer thanks, very easy to understand for someone who hasn't yet taken lin-alg!